# iOS - Reorder Items in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, core-data

I have a tableView and an array `locationsArray`. The locations array is filled on `viewDidLoad` from data in my CoreData.

I have implemented the reorder methods on the tableView and that works fine however I can't figure out how to save the reordered array back into CoreData. I've tried deleting everything in CoreData and just saving the new reorderedArray. Although this is obviously very costly resource wise it seems to just load the elements back into the array in a seemingly random order.

Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing or can you not store things in CoreData in a certain order?

Comment: Random order is faster, so if you need to preserve the order, use ordered relations or add an attribute to be used for sorting (comparison).

Comment: So I can make my own ordered set? Do you have any idea how this would work exactly?

Comment: If a relation fits your data model, enable "Ordered" checkbox and Xcode will generate an ordered set methods for you (there's a couple of old known issues which I'm sure you'll be able to resolve quickly using search). Otherwise an additional attributes can be used for comparison, use with `NSSortDescriptor` and the sortDescriptors array of `NSFetchRequest`, it doesn't require significant model changes but you'd have to maintain new attributes manually (keep track if the min/max values, make batch updates when inserting or removing elements, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly saying, it is impossible *to store objects in certain order*. You can only set the order for retrieved objects

When you retrieve `locationsArray` from CoreData, you have no any guaranties about their order. 
The only way - add field to your Managed Object that will be used to order your locations.

Than, on retrieval, you'll be able to use `locationsArray = [locationsArray sortedArrayUsing<#WhateverYouNeed#>];`.

You can, also, achieve this by using [sortDescriptors](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/sortDescriptors) property of NSFetchRequest. It will provide you with desired behaviour from the box. The only downside of it, that your NSSortDescriptor in that case cannot be defined by block, so if you ordering is using some complex approach, you'll need to sort the result with already fetched data

Comment: I see, so for my purposes where I'm not wanting to sort them per se but have the user choose the order is impossible with core data?

Comment: You want them to be sorted, when you retrieve it from core data. So, you need information stored to apply sorting. Then, when user changes order in table view - you change this "sorting info". Next time (next launch) you fetch data from Core data - you get it in user-defined order

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying, any idea on how this 'sorting info' would be stored/created?

Comment: For example, simple numeration would suffice - 0,1,2,... 
Another option, use ordered relation : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSRelationshipDescription_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSRelationshipDescription/ordered

Answer (score 0):

use the `predicate` to sort the array or after fetching the array from coredata sort it using

```
 NSArray *sortedlocationarray = [filteredlocationarray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

where filteredlocationarray is from coredata.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I'm not trying to sort the array.

Comment: treat each locationsArray item as model, have a property order using enumerateObjectsUsingBlock you can set order for each item and save the context